# Stanford CoreNLP caseless classifier in NLTK

Tags: python-2.7, nltk, stanford-nlp

I can't find the file english.conll.4class.caseless.distsim.crf.ser.gz from the zip file downloaded from  http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-ner-2015-04-20.zip .Can anyone please tell me how to get that caseless classfier from Stanford CoreNLP?

Comment: Change the `.properties` file appropriately to get the different models.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they are giving a direct gz files for caseless but are deriving via a makefile script, I checked in linux versions aswell and its not available there too, and somehow they are building it via truecaser it seems, While I dont totally understand the mechanism, below is a pointer, where I see the references in stanford core nlp git hub.

https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/d558d95d80b36b5b45bc21882cbc0ef7452eda24/scripts/ner/Makefile

You can search for "english.conll.4class.caseless.distsim.crf.ser.gz" in corenlp github for more pointers about it.

FYI.. you can also look at older versions, as its mentioned in the doc that they have provided them seperately.

Answer (score 0):

For those who face the same problem;

Download model jar from https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/index.html#download (There is a table that lists different models for different languages) and open/extract the jar content(e.g I used WinRar) then go to **edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner** directory you can find the **ser.gz** files for any model.